# Access ViewHolder parameter in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onactivityresult, recyclerview-layout

I have a `Recylerview` with `Button` and `TextView` as params. I am opening a **file chooser** on button click.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FileChooserAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    PojoClass pojoClass = pojoClassList_.get(position);
    holder.listViewName.setText(pojoClass.getListName());
    holder.fileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent filePickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            filePickIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(filePickIntent, 1);
        }
    });

}
```

Now, after selecting the file I am getting the file name in the `OnActivityResult` **displayName** variable. I want to set the `holder.textview.setText(displayName);` in `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
        // Get the Uri of the selected file
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String uriString = uri.toString();
        File myFile = new File(uriString);
        String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();


        if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
            displayName = myFile.getName();
        }
        // I want to place the holder.textview.setText(displayName) here
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Help me out , how to place the `ViewHolder` params to outside of the `Adapter`.

Comment: You need to add this name to your dataset of adapter and then call `#notifyItemChange()` on Adapter . Make `super.onActivityResult` as first line of the method .

Comment: use interfaces and when you gets the result `adapterobject.notifyItemChanged(position)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few notes**

The `ViewHolder`'s `holder` params is supposed to managed only by the `Adapter` class itself.

**What you can do**

- Hold a reference for the currently selected file/s received from the `onActivityResult`, either by using local store like (`List`, `SharedPreferences`, `Realm`, etc.)
- Populate the file chooser adapter again with the latest file items from the list
- Invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()`

> public void notifyDataSetChanged ()
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

**Read more on**

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the file name in your DataSet. 
And call `notifyDataSetChange()` on Activity Result.

Comment: pojo.setFileName(displayName);
 pojoClassList.set(tempPosition, pojo); Iam setting this under OnActivityResult,but same file name get updates for the previous lists.How to set the filename using position.

Comment: You will need to hold the position of a clicked item and update the list on same item.

Answer (score 0):

You should not handle click events in the adapter itself. Instead forward them back to activity/fragment using **interfaces**.

So when you click on the button, the method of the interface is called in the activity/fragment and from their you can easily detect the `onActivityResult()` method.

So when you get the name, update that value in your adapter dataset and notify your adapter for the changes.

A simple interface like this(Code is in Kotlin)

```
interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(position:Int)
}
```

And make your activity implement it. Now in your adapter class constructor pass the interface as a parameter.

```
AdapterClass(private val listener: OnClickListener)
```